# Haven't been able to add myisam sql into a server 5.5

Tags: mysql

A user send me his *.frm files and I haven´t been able to add this data base to mysql server 5.5.

I set my server variables to use as default engine = MYISAM

I place the files into the `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\data` directory

I stop the services and started it again expecting to see the new database as it started.

I am new at using mysql and haven't got a clue?

thanks.

Comment: Is there any error message or log message when you restart the services?

Answer (score 2):

frm files are unlikely to be enough -  they [contain only Meta information about the table.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/frm-file-format.html)

As far as I know, you absolutely need the .MYD (data) and .MYI (index) files as well for an intact database, but you can try to run [myisamchk](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/myisamchk.html) on what you have and see what happens.  Maybe it can recreate new, empty files for you.